# If $A$ has outer measure $0$, then it must be measurable?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $\mu^*: 2^X \rightarrow [0, \infty]$ be an outer measure.
Let $(X, M, \mu)$ be measure space, where $M$ is the collection of sets that satisfy Caratheodory condition, and $\mu = \mu^*|_M$.

Suppose $\mu^*(A) = 0$. I want to show that $A \in M$. Take any $E \subset X$, and applying Caratheodory,

$$\mu^*(E) \stackrel{?}{=}\mu^*(E \cap A) + \mu^*(E \cap A^c)$$

However, I have no idea how to proceed. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By monotonicity of outer measure:

$\mu^*(E\cap A)+\mu^*(E\cap A^c)=0+\mu^*(E\cap A^c)\leq\mu^*(E)$

And the reverse inequality is always true, simply by sub-additivity.